# Convert scala Map to Json in play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to convert a Map to Json in play framwork 2.6.x.
The code is like

```
  def toJson(x:Map[String, Object]) = {
    import play.api.libs.json._
    Json.toJson(x)
  }
```

I got error `No Json serializer found for type Map[String,Object]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`

The I add `writes` and code becomes:

```
  def toJson(x:Map[String, Object]) = {
    import play.api.libs.json._
    implicit val writes = Json.writes[Map[String, Object]]
    Json.toJson(x)
  }
```

I hit error. `No apply function found for scala.collection.immutable.Map`

Comment: You need to define manually writes for `Object` (do you really want to be able to serialize any `Object`?) and, probably, for Map as well (search here `play json map format`)

Comment: Agree with @Evgeny, the problem is not to do with the map, but with the Object type, i.e. how to turn the Object into a valid Json. You could possibly use some pattern matching in line with this [example](http://gfxmonk.net/2011/02/06/scala-trick-convert-object-to-option-a.html). Or tell us more about what Objects you expect.